# How can I prevent asp:RadioButtonList from rendering a HTML-Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I would like to render a simple list of  - Controls.
My ASP.NET Code-behind looks like:

```
RadioButtonList list = new RadioButtonList();
                    list.ID = rbl.name;
                    list.CssClass = rbl.cssClass;

                    foreach (radio radio in rbl.radio)
                    {
                        ListItem li = new ListItem();
                        li.Text = radio.label;
                        li.Value = radio.value;
                        li.Selected = radio.@checked;
                        list.Items.Add(li);

                    }
```

But the RadioButtonList renders automatically a HTML-Table. If I use HtmlInputRadioButton everything works fine but it crashes on RenderControl()

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should take a look into [RadioButtonList.RepeatLayout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatlayout.aspx)

> Use this property to specify whether the items in the RadioButtonList control are displayed in a table. If this property is set to RepeatLayout.Table, the items in the list are displayed in a table. If this property is set to RepeatLayout.Flow, the items in the list are displayed without a table structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the fastest perfect answer I've ever seen.

Comment: I would like the `label` to wrap around the `checkbox`

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer by Rubens Farias, ASP.NET 4 adds two new options to RadioButtonList.RepeatLayout, OrderedList and UnorderedList.