# Displaying ASP .NET controls in different browsers

Tags: css, asp.net

I have this markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestCSSTemplates.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">    
    <title></title>   
   <style type="text/css">
        ul { list-style: none }
        span { display:inline-block; text-align: right; width: 100px; }
        .DespliegaEnLinea { display: inline-block; }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <ul >
            <li>
                <span >Are you sure?: </span>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="DespliegaEnLinea">
                    <asp:ListItem>yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>no</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>                
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page is displayed in Chrome or Internet Explorer (9 or less with comptaibility mode activated), the page renders as I intended: all the content inside the *li* **tag** is in just one line.
However when the above page is displayed in Internet Explorer 11 (or 9, 8 without compatibility mode activated), it's rendered with a line break between the *span* **tag** and the *radiobuttonlist* **control**.

How can i make this page always render the content of the *li* **tag** in one line, regardless of the browers it's being used to see it?

Comment: You mean a [line break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), not a [breakpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint)? And why does it matter if there's an additional line break in the source?

Comment: It matters because the break is between the text and the control. I want these two things to be in one single line

Comment: You said in your title it's for compatibility. That's not going to affect compatibility.

Comment: Changed the title; I hope this makes my question more clear

Comment: What happens if you put your markup in the `<li>` on one line?

Comment: It's the same result. After a whole morning, I think I know what the problem is now. The RadioButtonList control is rendered as <table>. I have to redesing the page, avoid using that control

Comment: Ahh... perhaps [How can I prevent asp:RadioButtonList from rendering a HTML-Table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183827/how-can-i-prevent-aspradiobuttonlist-from-rendering-a-html-table) would help.