# Dynamic Radio button list- from line to row

Tags: c#, css, dynamic, radiobuttonlist

I would like to change the items in my radiobuttonlist to appear in a row and not vertical.they are dinamic... what is the way to do so?

**Edit.aspx**

```html
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**Edit.aspx.cs**

`Page_Init`

```cs
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  ListItem SignLi = new ListItem();
  switch (i) {
    case 1:
      SignLi.Text = "≠";
      SignLi.Value = i.ToString();
      SignLi.Selected = true;

      break;
    case 2:
      SignLi.Text = "=";
      SignLi.Value = i.ToString();
      break;
  }
  RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(SignLi);
}
```

please help!!
more details?
Should I use css? if yes, what is the things i need to write

```
{
  display: inline
}
```

I tried this one but maybe i should write something

Comment: can you share the output html ? ( even though is diyamic ) An example would help us figure it out. `display:inline` on the `radio` inputs should work ( if they are all siblings )

Comment: `RadioButtonList` by default render the list as `table`. A similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183846/863110